# How to avoid saving your own (office) traffic data in your database?

Tags: save, user-activity

I'm saving user actions on my website in my database, and this data will be used for further processing. However, I want to avoid saving my own actions on the website. These are the things I have tried so far -

1. IP address - My ISP provides me with a dynamic IP, so I dont think I can block away any particular IP address straight away.
2. /etc/hosts file - Tried putting in the url in this file so that it doesnt send data to that url. Doesn't work.
3. Set a cookie - Open a page on every browser that sets a user cookie, which I can detect and subsequently restrict. This option is not feasible in the long run. Also, people keep deleting cookies and remembering each time to open up that page everytime isn't feasible.

Is there any other way I can block saving my own data in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Lazy way. Never set a cookie, only check for a cookie. Don't collect data if you found a cookie. Put the cookie on your machine(s). Done.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Raff. To check a cookie, don't we have to set it initially? As I mentioned in point 3, we keep deleting cookies and I dont want to everyone in the office to set this cookie on every browser each time he/she deletes cookies. Its hard to remember. Is there anything that I'm missing?

Comment: You manually set the cookie ONLY for your machines. That way it doesn't matter what anyone else does, because why would they randomly set a cookie for your website? The cookie tells you to NOT collect data